# Aligning Images in WordPress Theme and Mysterious Border in Header

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I'm attempting to customize a WordPress theme.

Starting theme: http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Nexus/

I've gotten nearly where I want to in Chrome:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20040939/HeaderChrome.png

In Firefox, the images in the header are not lining up:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20040939/HeaderFF.png

In both browsers, there is an annoying border/shadow at the top of the page (see highlight area in Chrome screenshot above).

Live site is here:
http://makeminepop.com/

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "annoying shadow" is coming from the social links that you are not currently using on line 109 of style.css:

```
#et-social-icons {
    /* float: right; */
    /* width: 245px; */
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

Update:

I believe it is the `nav` element that is throwing off the image alignment. Try editing the following on line 104 of style.css

```
#top-navigation nav {
    overflow:hidden; <-- add this
    float: none; <-- modify this
}
```

Comment: No problem, I have a screenshot of the code you need for the logo if you want it. If you liked the answer/you found it useful you can upvote/accept it!

Comment: Yes, I'd love a screenshot of the code. And will be happy to upvote your answer

Comment: Hmm, not sure what I should be setting it to. Tried both of the following without success

#logo {
float: none;
}


#logo {
float: initial;
}

I would have thought the clearfix in the div (#top-navigation) immediately would sort out the logo float problem

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, it's not the logo that's the issue, it's actually the `nav` that's the issue, I'm checking now.

Answer (score 0):

this shadow was generated from #et-social-icons class. Just set the display:none to this class.

You can find the class in line:109 of the following css file.
http://makeminepop.com/wp-content/themes/Nexus/style.css?ver=4.3

Hope this help.